# Focus on user's current location in Titanium map view?

Tags: titanium, android-mapview, appcelerator, userlocation

I have a Mapview in my Titanium project. I can get the map to focus on a specefic latitude and longitude on load, but I can't seem to get it to focus on users currentLocation on load? What is the code for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your current location using [getCurrentPosition](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition-method.html) function and then focus map to this location.
Here is an example:

```
Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
    if (e.error) {
        return; 
    }

    storesMap.setLocation({
        latitude : e.coords.latitude,
        longitude : e.coords.longitude,
        latitudeDelta : 0.01,
        longitudeDelta : 0.01
    });
});
```